# GAE - Unable to instantiate - java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, objectify, gwtp

I do not know how to debug the following error : (could you explain me how to debug this kind of error ?).

One error is related to Guice Filter, and the other one is related to MessageBodyReader.

```
Initializing App Engine server
May 25, 2013 1:46:06 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\JUNO-WS\0-MS\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
May 25, 2013 1:46:06 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\JUNO-WS\0-MS\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
May 25, 2013 1:46:06 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\0-LIB\GAE\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\JUNO-WS\0-MS\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
May 25, 2013 1:46:06 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
May 25, 2013 1:46:07 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: Master/Slave
    Storage: C:\JUNO-WS\0-MS\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService load
INFO: Time to load datastore: 21 ms
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed guiceFilter: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@816c920{/,C:\JUNO-WS\0-MS\war}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:35)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:212)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:67)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:39)
    at com.MS.server.guice.GuiceRestEasyFilterDispatcher.init(GuiceRestEasyFilterDispatcher.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:230)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:216)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.registerProviders(RegisterBuiltin.java:70)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:31)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct public org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyConfiguration)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1861)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:704)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1159)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider.<init>(DocumentProvider.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:132)
    ... 37 more
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:8888/
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
May 25, 2013 1:46:09 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Linking modules
   Bootstrap link for command-line module 'com.MS.MS'
      Linking module 'MS'
         Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
            Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
jsonpath.js

May 25, 2013 1:46:39 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$PersistDatastore persist
INFO: Time to persist datastore: 19 ms
```

-- Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my error adding xalan-2.7.1.jar to the classpath.